# Why Hibernate is not rolling back the insert query from the table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I have a pseudo code like this :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.currentSession();
Connection connection = ((SessionImpl) session).connection();
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String sql = "INSERT into table...";
statement.execute(query);
connection.rollback(); // just for testing
```

When I execute this code, it should rollback the insert query but it is not doing the rollback.

I can see the data in the table. Then, what is the root cause ? Why is it not rolling back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**

> This code is to explain the behaviour for learning purposes. I do not recommend executing sql this way.

I am not sure as we don't know what else you have in your code. Here is my code, it rollbacks and commits as expected.

```
@Repository
public class DealRepositoryImpl implements DealRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    //This one gets rolled back
    @Override
    @Transactional 
    public void saveDealWithTransactionAnnotation() {
        try {
            Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
            Connection connection = ((SessionImpl) session).connection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "insert into deal (name, id)  values ('WithTransactionAnnotationAndRollback', 100)";
            statement.execute(sql);
            connection.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //This one also gets rolled back
    @Override
    public void saveDealWithoutTransactionAnnotation() {
        try {
            Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
            Connection connection = ((SessionImpl) session).connection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "insert into deal (name, id)  values ('WithoutTransactionAnnotationAndRollback', 200)";
            statement.execute(sql);
            connection.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //this one gets committed
    @Override
    public void saveDealWithCommit() {
        try {
            Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
            Connection connection = ((SessionImpl) session).connection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "insert into deal (name, id)  values ('withCommit', 400)";
            statement.execute(sql);
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah !! I have that

Comment: How should I change ? Should I remove it ?

Comment: There was no issue with code. I think the query is the problem. It's kind of reentrant insert query.

Comment: It's not reverting that.